# El buscador de mi formulario no regresa los registros completos cuando esta vacio

Tags: vb.net

Hola tengo un problema con el buscador de mi formulario no regresa los registros completos cuando esta vacio  se queda pegado con la ultima busqueda en vez de retornar todos los registros

codigo:

```
Private Sub txtBuscar_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBuscar.TextChanged
    Try
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dtv As DataView
    If txtBuscar.Text.Trim = 
        dtv = tb.Defaultview
        dtv.RowFilter = "Material like'%" & txtBuscar.Text &"%'"
        grdMateria.DataSource = dtv
        grdMateria.Refresh()
    Then 
        Exit Sub 
    Then
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End sub
```

Comment: Ahora podiras agregar un codigo que compile y funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Para que compile deberías escribir algo como lo siguiente:

```
Private Sub txtBuscar_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBuscar.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dtv As DataView
        If txtBuscar.Text.Trim.Length Then
            dtv = tb.Defaultview
            dtv.RowFilter = "Material like'%" & txtBuscar.Text & "%'"
            grdMateria.DataSource = dtv
            grdMateria.Refresh()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```